# Networkx: Regenerate the Random Geometric Graph with previously stored Node values and edges in file

Tags: python, networkx

I am generating Random Geometric Graph and storing node and edges 
information using `write_adjlist` into file.

Code: python1.py

```
G=nx.random_geometric_graph(10,0.5) 
filename = "ipRandomGrid.txt" 
fh=open(filename,'wb') 
nx.write_adjlist(G, fh) 
nx.draw(G) 
plt.show()
```

Now from the second file I am trying to generate the graph with the 
same node and edges information. I am using `read_adjlist` to find the 
information.

Code: python2.py

```
filename = "ipRandomGrid.txt" 
fh=open(filename, 'rb') 
G=nx.Graph() 
G=nx.read_adjlist("ipRandomGrid.txt") 
pos=nx.random_layout(G) 
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,nodelist=[1,2],node_color='b') 
nx.draw(G) 
plt.show()
```

It's showing me below error.

```
raise nx.NetworkXError('Node %s has no position.'%e) 
networkx.exception.NetworkXError: Node 1 has no position.
```

I think the problem is with the `pos` variable. Can some one help me to 
solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following interactive session:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.random_geometric_graph(10, 0.5)
>>> with open("junk.txt", "wb") as f:
...   nx.write_adjlist(G, f)
...
>>> G.nodes()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> with open("junk.txt", "rb") as f:
...   G2 = nx.read_adjlist(f)
...
>>> G2.nodes()
[u'1', u'0', u'3', u'2', u'5', u'4', u'7', u'6', u'9', u'8']
>>>
```

When reading the node list from the file, the nodes identities are treated as strings, not as numbers. Thus, you're getting an error because you're trying to plot two non-existent nodes `1` and `2`. Change them to strings (`'1'` and `'2'`) and it should work fine.

Comment: I changed it to String and it's now working. But I think due to pos=nx.random_layout(G) statement, I am not getting the same graph as expected. So I am not properly importing the node values and edges information which I exported in first code. Any idea how to import that correctly?

Comment: @KunjanSheth If you have another question about how to use NetworkX, post it as another question, hopefully more precisely stated than in your comment. Stackoverflow is a Q&A site, not a forum.